# Check the method was called in php

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have following php code in basic.php. How can I determine if the method `row()` was called? When I write next `<?php $basic->row(); ?>` it shows something like this - **the method was defined!**

**Example**

```
   $basic->container();     // container was called
    $basic->container();     // when called again, i need show some warning - CONTAINER CAN BE PUT ONLY ONCE and using exit() for example
```

This is the solution what i need

```
public function container(){

    static $container = false; 

    if ( $container ){ return; } else { print '<div class="container">'; } $container = true;

    }
```

Comment: Give it a variable which is set to 0 in the beginning and when the function is called, set it to 1 or smthg?

Comment: Your description is kind of tricky. Do you want to test if method exists, or do something after call, or echo something when you call that method?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if an object has a method or not before calling it, you can use [method_exists](http://php.net/method_exists).

```
if(method_exists($basic, 'row')) {
    $basic->row();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `echo` construct inside the row function like this:

```
// your code
function row(){
  echo "Function called!";
  ....
}
```

This will print the text "Function called!" everytime you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand if you mean really a call or if the method is defined.

As @Prasanth said, if you mean if the method is defined - method_exists will be a solution.

Otherwise, you can check my answer here: [Cahining pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948744/cahining-pattern/20949421#20949421)

It's related to your problem, as you need a generic way to register a method been called before.

You, ofcourse, can write down

```
public $_row = false;
public function row() {
    $this->_row = true;
    // some stuff
}
```

and later:

```
if (!$basic->_row) {
    $basic->row();
}
```

You just need a property where you will set a value, which corresponds to your script later. I.e. here the default value is false - it means the method hasn't been called yet. Once method is called, it changes it to true. You are testing if the value is default (false) then call.

You may not change the value to true, but to the string you wanted. E.g. `$this->_row = 'the method was defined!'` Or set to true and print the string, if `$this->_row == true`.

Answer (score 0):

I just add it as an answer ... try smthg like this:

```
function row(){
    if($wascalled === true) {
        echo "The function was called";
    }

    //your Code here

    $wascalled = true;
}
```

So, the first time you call the function, nothing happens, if you call it more, the message will appear. It looks ugly and i dont see much sense in it, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

[Reference](https://www.php.net/function_exists)

```
bool function_exists ( string $function_name )
```

Parameters The **$function_name, as a string.**

Returns `TRUE` if `function_name exists` and is a function, `FALSE` otherwise.

**Note:**
This function will return `FALSE` for `constructs`, such as `include_once` and `echo`.

```
<?php
if (function_exists('function_name')) {
    echo "IMAP functions are available.<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "IMAP functions are not available.<br />\n";
}
?>
```

Take this as an example

```
<?php 
if (function_exists('foo')) { 
  print "foo defined\\n"; 
} else { 
  print "foo not defined\\n"; 
} 
function foo() {} 

if (function_exists('bar')) { 
  print "bar defined\\n"; 
} else { 
  print "defining bar\\n"; 
  function bar() {} 
} 
print "calling bar\\n"; 
bar(); // ok to call function conditionally defined earlier 

print "calling baz\\n"; 
baz(); // ok to call function unconditionally defined later 
function baz() {} 

qux(); // NOT ok to call function conditionally defined later 
if (!function_exists('qux')) { 
  function qux() {} 
} 
?> 
Prints: 
  foo defined 
  defining bar 
  calling bar 
  calling baz 
  PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function qux()
```

[Alternative method](https://www.php.net/method_exists)

Answer (score 0):

You can use magic method [__call](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).

```
 class Basic{

 function row(){
    print ' Call method '.__METHOD__.'<br/>';
 }

 function __call($method,$params){
    if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
        call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
    }else{
        print 'Class '.__CLASS__.' hasn`t method "'.$method.'"<br/>';
    }
  }
}

$basic = new Basic();
$basic->row();
$basic->fetch();

// output
Call method Basic::row
Class Basic hasn`t method "fetch"
```